# How to maintain Transform of objects when importing from Blender to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I have imported my Blender model into Unity, complete with the armature which animates correctly.

However, I now want to manipulate the bone transforms in Unity (e.g. make the head bone "look at" the player). However, the transform for the head bone (and many other bones), seems to have changed after being imported into Unity. E.g. the 'Z' direction is no longer upward. How can I make sure the Transforms are consistent between Blender and Unity?

Below is the transform of the head bone in Blender.

[image]

And here is the transform of the head bone after being imported to Unity.

[image]

Comment: you must set the origin correctly in Blender or Cheetah3D.

Comment: note that ***YOU MUST*** model with "z forward".  you MUST have "z" as the forward walking direction of the dog.

Comment: Thanks for the help. As far as I am aware, I have modeled with " z forward". If I select the wolf model parent in Unity, the z shows as facing forward. It is only when I select the armature node and any children of the armature that the Z shows as anything other than forward. My second screenshot shows the transform of the head bone in particular.

Comment: Hey Jonny.  You know ... when you do let's say cars.  Every single piece of the car has to be z-forward.  Something that often catches people out: you see the left and right wheel. It's natural to just take your left wheel model and turn it around to make the right one. But you can't!  The modeller has to actually make a left-facing and right-facing wheel.  I'm afraid **I don't know the case for wolf-parts!**  Heh.  As you say ... "seems to have changed after being imported into Unity" ... it is possible that this is indeed the problem. You must have Y up and Z forward...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a 3D environment there are several ways to orient the axes when you are referring to what is front, back, up, down. Blender and Unity (and other 3d apps) use different coordinate systems, where blender has +z pointing upwards Unity has +y.

You will find that exporting from blender to unity handles the axes conversion so that the axes match the conventions used in each app, this is why the bone axes don't match what you expected.

Unless you have trouble with your animations going wrong, the easiest solution is to get used to the two apps using different axis systems for the same models.

To be technical blender uses the [right-handed cartesian coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#In_three_dimensions) with +z pointing up, this is more common in 3D CAD applications and matches placing a graph on the desk in front of you and raising a z-axis from it. It is also common for some 3D apps to have the z-axis pointing backwards as it matches with the z-depth that refers to the distance from the camera, and fits with having x0,y0 at the bottom left of the window.

Answer (score 0):

- In FBX export settings, select "Armatures"
- In Primary Bone Axis, select "Z Axis"
- In Secondary Bone Axis, select "-X Axis"